# Mounting an unknown filesystem type

Tags: mount, filesystem, bsd

I'm in possession of a 100G disk that sports a partition that I have not been able to mount.

Using `partx -o type` on the device tells me the partition has type 0xa5, generally associated with BSD operating systems. Executing a plain `mount` command tells me I need to specify a filesystem type.

From the 0xa5 marker I concluded it could be some version of ufs. `mount -t ufs -o ufstype=ufs2` (the default for modern FreeBSD, right?) did not yield a successful mount. `dmesg` complains about missing "magic numbers". Trying a number of the alternative options for `ufstype` has the same results.

Questions:

1. Does anyone have any tips for figuring out how to access the data on this partition?
2. Is there a generic way to autodetect/mount partitions that I could use?

Answer (score 2):

Have you verified that there is a real partition there, as opposed to random data in the block containing the partition table?  (Use `fdisk` or `cfdisk` and verify that any partition start and end numbers make basic sense.  `fdisk` at least will notice obvious things like illegal block values or end blocks before start blocks and warn you that the partition table is invalid.)

`parted`/`gparted` may be able to identify filesystems for you.  Sometimes `file -s` can do so as well.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo file -Ls /dev/sdb1` will give you more information. Replace 'sdb1' with the proper device node name. `cat /proc/partitions` and/or `dmesg | tail` can help you figure out which is the correct device.